# Friendly users for new Kana learning iOS application

Tags: discussion

I am looking for friendly users to give feedback for a new application to learn Hiragana and Katakana. Where can I find this kind of users best? I'm not sure I'm supposed to be placing such questions here. If not, someone may point out to me please. よろしくお願いします